# Angle from vector

Tags: algorithm, vector

Say I have point A (20,20) and point B (60,60).

The resulting vector would be 40, 40. How could I get the angle of this vector?

By this I mean, imagine there is an imaginary circle around the origin.

I guess sort of what atan2 does but without atan2.

Thank

Comment: What's wrong with `Math.atan2`?

Comment: Without doing any calculations in my head I'm guessing the angle for the resulting vector (40,40) is `45` degrees or `π/4` radians... call it a hunch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by angle, since you only give one vector in your example.  But, given two vectors, you can find the angle between them like so:

Given vectors **a** and **b**, normalize both of them.  Then, dot(**a**,  **b**) = cos(θ), where θ is the angle between the two vectors.  Use arccos to find θ.

Answer (score 3):

Presuming that you want to find the angle of the vector against the X axis (in JavaScript):

```
var vector = {x: 40, y: 40};

var rad = Math.atan(vector.y/vector.x)
var deg = rad * 180/Math.PI;

alert(deg); // 45 deg
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the link that will show you how to find the angle bewteen two vectors:

http://www.wikihow.com/Find-the-Angle-Between-Two-Vectors

Comment: I think OP is asking about the polar angle of the difference vector `B-A`. At least that's the only way I see of coming up with (40, 40) as the "resulting vector".