# How to move an object uniformly from one point to another at a fixed angle?

Tags: java, game-physics

[image]

In my 2d java game, I need to move projectiles from Enemy object to Player object in a straight line. I did some research and found out that I can use atan2(x, y) method of Math class to get the angle, but then how am i supposed to move the projectile in that particular angle(direction)? Any ideas would be very helpful.

Comment: If you're attempting any kind of spatial game programming, it will be a painful experience unless you've learnt some basic geometry and trigonometry first. I suggest you pick up a decent maths textbook before going too much further.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21483999/using-atan2-to-find-angle-between-two-vectors or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6222671/angle-from-vector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation of movment with constant speed is simple

```
positionX = startPositionX + speedX * time 
positionY = startPositionX + speedY * time
```

where

```
speedX = speed * sin(angle)
speedY = speed * cos(angle)
```

But most of the game use incremental aproach

```
posX = posX + speedX / lengthOfTick
posY = posY + speedY / lengthOfTick
```